# I get a empty list when using then async and await functions

Tags: flutter, dart

it's the first time to write a Flutter code so i am confused,
when i tring to get data from API, API working normaly and return a response with data but after that i need to save this data in a list and give it as a variable in another Function but it still empty

```
Widget number() {
  List number_list=[];
  get_number().then((value) {number_list=value.values.toList();
  print(number_list);// i am giting a list with Values 
   });


  print(number_list); // i am giting an empty list 
  return ListView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    children: buttons(number_list),
  );
}
```

Comment: See https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: when using await follow the pattern Future<type> func(string parm) async{}   then call the future using a promise func().then((value){});

Comment: add your get_number() function

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your 'get_number' function an async function and then use 'await' to wait for the API's response to reach and then continue with creating variables and widgets out of the response. The code becomes like this:

```
Widget number() {
  List number_list=[];
  var value = await get_number();
  number_list=value.values.toList();

  return ListView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    children: buttons(fleet_list),
  );
}
```

if you don't use 'await', your code won't wait for getting data from API.

Comment: if i using await i have to use a async and after that i have to use Future and i wanna returen widget not Future Widget. but am using await in get_number() function

Answer (score 0):

try using a Future and a promise

```
List number_list=[];
  Future<List<int>> get_number() async{
    return [1,2,3,4];
  }
  
  foo(){
  get_number().then((values) {
      number_list=values;
      print(number_list);// i am giting a list with Values 
   });
  }
  
 foo();
```